# Open links, one after another

Tags: javascript, settimeout, window.open

I'm making a website where I'm opening a new window every 30 seconds. I got it to open the new windows properly, but I would like it to close the last window opened before opening the new one, so only one window is open at a time. How would I do this? Here's my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win() {
    window.open("http://www.wol.com");
    setTimeout(window.open('http://www.bol.com'),35000);
    setTimeout(window.open('http://lol.com'),70000);
    setTimeout(window.open('http://col.com'),105000);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you realize that subsequent window openings will likely be blocked by the popup blocker?

Comment: yes, but i just allowed all popups... ;( im a noob

Comment: That's fine if you are the only customer of this code, but if you expect other people to use this web page, then their browsers probably won't permit the new windows beyond the first one and you cannot expect them to allow all popups.

Comment: i'll definetly keep it in mind!

Answer (score 1):

You can close a window opened by calling window.close on window.open's return value. So:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win() {
    var wol,bol,lol;
    wol=window.open("http://www.wol.com");
    setTimeout(function(){window.close(wol);bol=window.open('http://www.bol.com')},35000);
    setTimeout(function(){window.close(bol);lol=window.open('http://lol.com')},70000);
    setTimeout(function(){window.close(lol);window.open('http://col.com')},105000);

}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but my tabs don't close :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string array to store all of the links, and then iterate through that loop calling open and close after 30 seconds. Using a loop and abstracting open/close allows you to have as many links as you'd like.

```
var linkArray = ['http://www.wol.com', 'http://www.bol.com', 'http://lol.com', ['http://col.com']

function openWin(link) { 
    var currentWindow = window.open(link);
    setTimeout(currentWindow.close(), 30000);
}

function runLinks() {
    for(var i = 0; i< linkArray.length; i++) {
          openWin(linkArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to call `window.close()` using the window handle that you want to actually close.  You can't just pass it a link like you are doing and expect it to work properly.  Other answers here illustrate the correct way to close a window you've opened.

Comment: ummm something isn't working, I can't execute it, it says there is a problem with the first function. Could it be the window.close causin the whole function to give me an error? Instead of link do I need to write something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here a small interval loop for calling urls. Feel free to add an array for different URLS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastWindow = "";
    setInterval(function(){
        if(lastWindow != ""){ lastWindow.close(); }
        lastWindow = window.open("url");
    }, 30000);
</script>
```